# Как можно в Битрикс при регистрации сделать автоматическое создание логина пользователя на основе его Email?

Tags: битрикс

Необходимо оставить в форме регистрации только поля Email и телефон, поле логин убрать, сам логин пользователя должен будет формироваться на основе его Email.

Как можно реализовать регистрацию пользователей в Битрикс, так чтобы при регистрации пользователь не заполнял поле логин в форме регистрации, а логин формировался на основе Email ? Например, если у пользователя Email - max88@gmail.com то логин должен быть таким же - max88@gmail.com

Comment: используя обработчик события регистрации в файле init.php или кастомизировав компонент регистрации.

Answer (score 2):

Логин это обязательное для заполнение поле, без костылей вряд ли получится.

Алгоритм может быть такой:

1) Кастомизируем шаблон регистрации - скрываем (style = "display: none;") input с логином, сам input заполняем заглушкой - случайно сгенерированной строкой.

2) создаем в init.php обработчик на событие OnBeforeUserRegister, в котором подменяем значение логина на указанный пользователем email.